# dust.js object print

Tags: dust.js

Is it possible to print an object without knowing it's attributes? I am trying to debug why attributes of a certain object are not accessible in a view.

```
{#object}
  {attr}
{/object}
```

In case of above example nothing gets printed instead of attr value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the contextDump [helper](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers).

```
{#object}
  {@contextDump/}
{/object}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/smfoote/8UfJL/